# Creating switches for piece wise defined function?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

How can I create "switches"  [*the term may be new, but I'll explain it*] for piecewise defined functions ? Suppose a function:

> $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\alpha\;,x\in D_1\\\beta\;,x\in
>  D_2\end{cases}\\\text{wherein domain of f is D and range R, also
>  }D_1\cup D_2=D$$

So, after creating switches $S_1, S_2$:

> $$f(x)=S_1(x)\alpha+S_2(x)\beta$$

So that

> $$S_1(x)=0\;\forall x\in D_2 \;and\;S_1(x)=1\;\forall x\in D_1    
>  \\S_2(x)=0\;\forall x\in D_1 \;and\;S_1(x)=1\;\forall x\in D_2 $$

Afer some thought I created one for a simple case:

> $$\LARGE \tan^{-1}{\frac 1x}=\cot^{-1}x-\pi.\left(\frac{1-\frac{|x|}x}2\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [indicator functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Otherwise, here's my attempt for the special case where $D_1 = (-\infty, c)$ and $D_2 = (c, \infty)$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{(\beta - \alpha)|x - c| + (\beta + \alpha)(x - c)}{2(x - c)}
$$